# How to recover when stuck by executing wrong shell commands?

Tags: linux, shell, git-bash

I'm using Git Bash 2.9.0-64-bit in win7 64bit.
Here is my shell code

```
function sum1_x(){
a=$1
while [ $a -ge 1 ]; do
    sum=$[$sum + $a]
    a=$[$a - 1]
done

echo $sum
}

sum $1
```

In Git Bash,my type history is as follows:

> wen@PC-WEN MINGW64 /d/git/ (dev)
>   $sh sum1_x.sh
>   exit
>   :q
>
> quit
>   quit()
>   exit()

After I typed `sh sum1_x.sh`,I can no longer execute any shell command.I tried many commands as shows.I know there are bugs in my script,but how can I get back to execute shell script facing this kind of problems? Nothing can I do now.

Comment: Maybe you're in an infinite loop in your script?

Comment: Can I stop it directly?@AvihooMamka

Comment: You can kill the terminal, or force it to exit by clicking the "x" button, or you can determine the PID of the process and kill it.

Comment: I'm sorry,clicking 'x' won't work,but CTRL + 'c' works.Although I don't know the reason.@AvihooMamka

Comment: It seems that you started the script without any parameter, but the function sum in your scripts expects to parameter.

Comment: Yes,I know it.I just want to know the right action to let me be able to execute shell commands.@AvihooMamka

Comment: You can do `./sum1_x.sh PARAM" for instance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You have several problems with your script:

1. you have function `sum1_x`  but you are calling `sum $1`
2. You didn't check that input value exists, because of it you stuck in infinite loop

Here is the corrected script with check that input argument is exists:

```
function sum1_x(){
a=$1
while [ $a -ge 1 ]; do
  sum=$[$sum + $a]
  a=$[$a - 1]
done

echo $sum
}

if [ -z "$1" ]; then  # check that input parameter is exists
echo "No input"
else
sum1_x $1
fi
```

### How to stop program:

1. `Ctrl + 'c'`
2. Open new mingw and find `pid` of the progrman via `ps -aux | grep "sum1_x.sh"`
   and then use kill pid to kill the program

Comment: I tried your second solution,but it returns 'ps:user x unknown'.@Arseniy

Comment: @YuanWen try ps axf

Answer (score 0):

As shows in the question,the shell script contains many bugs.The command `sh sum1_x.sh` was wrong too.It should be replaced by command `sh sum1_x.sh 9` or things like it.After I fixed these bugs,it runs without problems and print the right sum.

But I still didn't know how to shop the shell script.Fortunately,By accident,I clicked Ctrl & c,and I can input shell commands again.